# Prove this theorem about infinity set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

X is infinity if, and only if, $X\neq \emptyset$ and,  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\nexists f : I_n \rightarrow X$ surjective. ($I_n = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$)

I'm shure that if X is infinity isn't exists this surjective function because if we have a surjective function and a finite domain set, the set of imagens essentially need to be finite. But, I can't prove that if f never be surjective and the domain is finite, X is essentially infinite. Can Help Me? :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ is not infinite. Then $|X|=k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. $X$ can be enumerated as $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k\}$. Define $f_k:\{1,2\ldots,k\} \to X$ defined by $f_k(i)=x_i$ for $i=1,2, \ldots,k$. This shows that $f_k$ is surjective.

Comment: You just proved the contrapositive of one of the directions. Not a proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

One cannot claim "$X$ is infinity," the statement should say something like $|X|$ is infinite, etc.

It is easier to prove $|X|$ is finite $\iff$ there exists a surjective function $I_n \to X$, which is logically equivalent.

One direction: if $X$ is finite, then clearly there exists some $I_n$ and $f:I_n \to X$ that is bijective (by definition.)

On the other hand, if there exists a such a function, then $X$ must have been finite, since a surjective function $f:I_n \to X$ implies that $\infty>|I_n| \geq |X|$.

To see the last line, note that $|I_n|=n$. Assume that $|X|>n+1$. Then there could not exist a surjective function since each $i \in I$ can take at most one value under $f$,  a contradiction.